# Upload an image from input type file to a server

Tags: php

I am struggling to upload a file to MySQL, what is wrong here? Cannot figure it out for 3 hours, but it should be relatively simple...

HTML:

```
 <form>
 <input class="form-control" type="file" accept="image/jpg" id="pic_in_in" required>
 <button class="btn" onclick="create_band()">Upload</button>
 </form>
```

JS:

```
function create_band() {
console.log("ADDED");

    let obj = {
        image : $('input[type=file]').val()

    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "db/addBand.php",
        data: obj,
        success: function (res) {
            loadBandsData();
            $('#pic_in_in').val("");

        }
    });
 }
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$image = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];


    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'va_final_project');
    $query = "INSERT INTO va_band_name (band_img) VALUES '$image'
                
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
   mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: @Ken Lee, Could you please provide an example? I am trying to upload a file via input form then pass it into an object with JS and send this object with ajax to php, and php would add it to the database into blob column. I am new to this, so I understand that it has to copy from one part to another, but I don’t understand in sintax how do I do it, since my way does’t work

Comment: Please see my answer as a suggested solution.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself. You are probably using MySQL or MariaDB as your DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload file thru ajax, use FormData, and to store data of image into a db table (say in a LONGBLOB field), you may use fread and send_long_data to do the job.

Please find below the code (including one to let you view the uploaded photos):

HTML

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form>
 <input class="form-control" type="file" accept="image/jpg" id="pic_in_in" required>
 <button class="btn" onclick="create_band()">Upload</button>
</form>

<script>

function create_band() {
//console.log("ADDED");

  var file_data = $('#pic_in_in').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
   
    $.ajax({
        async:false,
        url: 'addBand.php', // <-- point to server-side PHP script 
        dataType: 'text',  // <-- what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,                         
        type: 'post',
        success: function(php_script_response){
            alert(php_script_response); // <-- display response from the PHP script, if any
        }
     });

}
 </script>
```

PHP (addBand.php)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

  // Read the file 
  $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
  $image = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
  fclose($fp);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO va_band_name (band_img) VALUES (?)";

   $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $null = NULL; 

   $statement->bind_param('b', $null);
   $statement->send_long_data(0, $image); 
   $statement->execute();
   
 $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($statement);

 if($check == 1){
   $res = 'Image was uploaded';
 }else{
   $res = 'Something went wrong!';
 }
echo $res; 
}
?>
```

PHP (view uploaded photos):

```
Uploaded photos (if any):
<br>

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM va_band_name";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();

foreach($result as $row){

echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['band_img']).'" width="200" height=auto/>';
echo "<hr>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding the *enctype* atribute to your form?

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

This is code from w3schools.com, best of luck and hope it helps